# How can I find the last instance of substring A before the first instance of substring B?

Tags: javascript, string

I'd like to not use Regex if it isn't necessary for the task. I've got some text in a textarea...

```
<textarea>
    <!-- language-all: lang-cs -->
    [Exception filters][1] give developers the ability to add a condition (in 
    the form of a boolean expression) to a `catch` block allowing the `catch` to 
    execute only if the condition evaluates to `true`.  

    This is different from using an `if` statement inside the `catch` block and 
    re-throwing the exception since this approach stops propagating debug 
    information linked to the original exception.
</textarea>
```

...and I've chosen a line of the text that I'm interested in manipulating, let's call it `substring B`.

```
var substringB = 're-throwing the exception since this approach stops propagating';
```

I want to find the linebreak (`\n`), let's call it `substring A`, that comes before `substring B`, if one exists. By find, I mean get the linebreak's index in the string.

Can this be done with the JS string functions? Do we need to use Regex for this?

Comment: Split at line breaks, and add up the length of all parts (plus 1 for each line break), up until you reach the line you are interested in ...?

Comment: Could you create a new substring that includes everything from the beginning *up to* `Substring B`, and then search that new substring for `Substring A`?

Comment: `string.indexOf("\n")` returns the position of a new line. You can pass a second argument for the start position. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: text.split(substringB)[0].lastIndexOf(substringA);

Comment: `str.split("b")[0].split("a").pop()`

Comment: @dandavis now you're just showing off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find `substringB`, then use [`.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) to find `substringA` searching backwards from there. Both `.indexOf()` and `.lastIndexOf()` have an optional *fromIndex* argument.

```js
var text = document.querySelector("textarea").value;

var substringB = 're-throwing the exception since this approach stops propagating';
var substringA = '\n';

var subBIndex = text.indexOf(substringB);
var subAIndex = text.lastIndexOf(substringA, subBIndex);

console.log(subAIndex);
```

```html
<textarea>
    <!-- language-all: lang-cs -->
    [Exception filters][1] give developers the ability to add a condition (in 
    the form of a boolean expression) to a `catch` block allowing the `catch` to 
    execute only if the condition evaluates to `true`.  

    This is different from using an `if` statement inside the `catch` block and 
    re-throwing the exception since this approach stops propagating debug 
    information linked to the original exception.
</textarea>
```

Note: the simple code I've shown assumes that `substringB` will be found. You can add an `if` test to check that `subBIndex != -1` if you want to explicitly test that before looking for `substringA`.

Comment: Yep. This should do it. No need to split then count as other comments suggest - it's just wasteful.

Comment: @Vld and *that* is the reason I go ahead and ask on SO, and learn how to do it *correctly* in 2 minutes rather than experiment with my own wasteful solution (I was thinking of trying the splitting approach before I asked).